# Detecting unknown class in a bayes classifier

Tags: classification, bayesian

If you have a bayes classifier trained for a set of classes, how to detect if the output is significant enough to choose a class? It would be useful for detecting samples wich can't be asigned to a class. I have tried testing if the class probability is above mean+2*stddev of the probabilities of all the clases, but I don't think it will be robust.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider log-likelihood ratios.  Consider `R(C)  = log(P(C|D)/P(~C| D)`, where `C` is the class, `D` are the features.  Then you probably want to ensure that `R(C)` is greater than some positive amount.

Comment: I'll look into this and do some tests

Comment: The likelihood ratio isn't going to help him here--at least not as you describe. He knows the *relative* "probabilities" P(C1|D), P(C2|D), ... , P(CN|D), but doesn't know how to normalize them properly because he has a non-exhaustive set of classes; i.e., SUM over i=1 to N of P(Ci|D) is NOT equal to unity because other unknown classes exist that contribute to the probability sum in unknown ways. Therefore, even though he can do a P(C1|D)/P(C2|D) likelihood ratio (the unknown normalization factor drops out), he CANNOT calculate P(~C|D) because his P(Ci|D) values aren't true probabilities.